# Get Id of the row clicked from the table in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to get `Id` of row clicked when a user clicks a button.

My code is as below.

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ProductGrid">
    <tr>
        <th>P Id</th>
        <th>P Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(Mvc4API.linqtosql.tblProduct prod in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@prod.Pid</td>
            <td>@prod.Pname</td>
            <td>@prod.Price</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="ids" id="btnpartial" value="showdetail" onclick="getview()"></button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I tried:-

```
function getview() {
    debugger;
    var productId = $("#ProductGrid .ids").closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
});
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate id attributes are invalid html. Remove the `id` attribute and the `onclick` and use

```
$('.ids').click(function() {
    var productId = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).text();
});
```

Alternatively, add the value in a `data` attribute

```
<button type="button" class="ids" data-id="@prod.Pid"></button>
```

and use

```
$('.ids').click(function() {
    var productId = $(this).data('id');
});
```

Note that your current selector - `$("#ProductGrid .ids")` returns all the button elements, not the one you clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Just update the tag.

```
button type="button" class="ids" id="btnpartial" value="showdetail" onclick="getview()"
```

to

```
button type="button" class="ids" id="btnpartial" value="showdetail" onclick="getview(this)"
```

It will give you the id in script.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button tag like this

```
<td><button type="button" class="ids" id="btnpartial" value="showdetail" onclick="getview(@prod.Pid)"></button></td>
```

and the JS function like this

```
function getview(id) {
    debugger;
    var productId = id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

**View**

```
<td><button type="button" class="ids" id="btnpartial" value="showdetail" onclick="getview(@prod.Pid)"></button></td>
```

**Script**

```
function getview(x)
{
   var id = x; //Id will get here.
}
```